# NHibernate Inherited Class but no need to persist

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, inheritance, persistence

I have a class, Order, which I persist to a database using NHibernate.  There is a folder futher down in the web application that contains an object that inherits from Order, for our purposes, we can call it CustomOrder.  I use CustomOrder to place a few properties onto the Order object for UI purposes.  The properties don't actually have to be saved to the database.

When I pass the CustomOrder class to my generic save method that just takes in an Order object, NHibernate complains:

Unknown entity class: CustomOrder.

I don't need to persist the custom fields to the database, but I'd like to keep this inheritance structure.  Am I thinking in the wrong terms or doing something I shouldn't be doing?

**Save Code**

```
public object Save(Order obj, object userID) {
        Order o = (Order)obj;  
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

        session.Save(o);
```

After the case in the first line of the method, .NET still identifies it as CustomerOrder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **You cannot change the type of a instance in .NET.** There is no casting or whatever that makes it possible.
2. **When loading the instance from the DB, NHibernate wants to create the same type you stored.** That's why it wants a mapping for CustomOrder.

How ever you implement it: you need to create a new instance of Order.

```
// get the CustomOrder from somewhere
CustomOrder customOrder;
// create an instance of Order and store it.
session.Save(customOrder.GetOrder());


class CustomOrder
{

    // just one of many ways: a method on the CustomOrder to create 
    // instance of Order
    public GetOrder()
    {
        return new Order()
        {
            property1 = this.property1,
            property2 = this.property2,
            property3 = this.property3
        }
    }
}
```

You can use Reflection to do this automatically.
Or take a look at [MemberwiseClone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I was going to suggest (and the only way to accomplish this).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I believe that you should be able to specify that the derived class should be persisted as an object of the base class in the hibernate mapping file.

Comment: Is there a workaround to having to provide a discriminator for a subclass?